# How can I get my C++ program to compile on Unix?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, g++

I am working on a school project in C++ and am using our schools unix server to write it as instructed by the professor. I am using vim and g++ to compile.

This project is built off another project, Lab0 which I had no trouble getting to build after some help from the TA, but had to do some weird stuff to get it to build  (#include LinkedSortedList.cpp file at the bottom of LinkedSortedList.h). Everyone in the class did this weird stuff with #include .cpp file.

First, here are the files and what #includes they have for Lab0 which is compiling fine:

(The post is not showing my tabs in my makefile but they're there!)

makefile:

```
main: *.cpp *.h

g++ -o LSL main.cpp

clean:

rm -f *.o LSL*
```

Lab0 (The one that builds), is like this:

Files:

main.cpp (NOT Templated):

```
#include "LinkedSortedList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

SortedList.h (Templated):
    Nothing

LinkedNode.h (Templated):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

LinkedSortedList.h (Templated):

```
#include "SortedList.h"
#include "LinkedNode.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "LinkedSortedList.cpp" // At the bottom fo this file above the #endif to get the program to compile from what the TA told me to do for lab0 due to the templated class.
```

LinkedSortedList.cpp (Templated):
    Nothing

No problems building and running this project.

Here is my issue:

Below is lab1, the one I am having trouble with and Lab1 uses all the files from Lab0 just adds Employee.h and Employee.cpp.

Lab1 (The one that won't build) is like this:

Files:

lab1.cpp:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Employee.h"
#include "LinkedSortedList.h"
```

SortedList.h (Templated):
    Nothing

LinkedNode.h (Templated):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

LinkedSortedList.h (Templated):

```
#include "SortedList.h"
#include "LinkedNode.h"
#include "Employee.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "LinkedSortedList.cpp" // At the bottom fo this file above the #endif to get the program to compile from what the TA told me to do for lab0 due to the templated class.
```

LinkedSortedList.cpp (Templated):
    Nothing

Employee.h (NOT templated):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
```

Employee.cpp (NOT templated):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

(The post is not showing my tabs in my makefile but they're there!)

```
makefile:

main: *.cpp *.h

g++ -o LSL lab1.cpp

clean:

rm -f *.o LSL*
```

Errors I get:

Here are the errors I am getting. It seems like the Employee.cpp/Employee.h files are not being seen. Any ideas??

`` unixserver:Lab1> make
g++ -o LSL lab1.cpp
/tmp/ccamnaqx.o: In function createRecord()':
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference toEmployee::Employee()'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x477): undefined reference to Employee::setLastName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x4f2): undefined reference toEmployee::setFirstName(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x589): undefined reference to Employee::setId(int)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x5ce): undefined reference toEmployee::setSalary(int)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x60e): undefined reference to Employee::setDepartment(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x67c): undefined reference toEmployee::setPhoneNumber(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x6ea): undefined reference to Employee::setAddress(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x758): undefined reference toEmployee::setHireDate(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'
lab1.cpp:(.text+0x7c6): undefined reference to `Employee::setEmailAddress(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: * [main] Error 1 ``

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Step 1 to solution: use code formatting.

Comment: You also need to organize what code is where, your question is very hard to follow.

Comment: No need for three downvotes here imho since the question itself was pretty much ok (although the formatting was awkward). @DemiSheep: please take care to use the StackOverflow code editor to format code and other elements correctly. It makes it easier to read...

Comment: God bless the editor who has taken the effort to format this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compile `Employee.cpp` and link it into the executable:

```
g++ -o LSL lab1.cpp Employee.cpp
```

It could be that the same goes for `LinkedSortedList.cpp` (its purpose is not entirely clear to me).

Answer (score 3):

Your makefile for your second project only compiles lab1.cpp and not your other cpp files.  You have two others (Employee.cpp and LinkSortedList.cpp) that you need to account for.

Also, please learn how to properly format code here on this site.  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for the link I was trying to find that Urgh!